# Position second element under fieldcontain form element

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, jquery-mobile

Is it possible to position text under a fieldcontain-style textarea (horizontally starting at the second column) in jquerymobile? If possible I would like to use native jquerymobile markup rather than creating overhead css/javascript.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z8w6r/)

```
---------------------------------
               ----------------
label          | Textarea     |
               ----------------
           --->|ANOTHER TEXT ALIGNED LEFT WITH "Textarea" ABOVE
anotherLabel   ....
---------------------------------
```

I have also added this posting to a github issue request [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4641). They also recommend using my own css definitions which is not actually what I hoped for because I do not want to create much overhead css and certainly do not want to modify the jquery css right now.

Comment: Hey man, is this Css question do you mean `margin left`? Sorry if I sound bit thick but what are you trying to do bruv!

Comment: After looking to fiddle, it seems, you need to set left margin for the text "230 of 250 chars left".

Comment: @KutePHP setting a fixed margin to a mobile framework that has a responsive design down to mobile devices would be the wrong approach I suppose.

Comment: @Tats_innit Okay, jquerymobile devs suggested using margin-left and setting my own css class for that purpose. I'd vote for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved the issue. Works absolutely fine!

```
@media all and (min-width: 450px) {
    .ui-my-addition-element-info {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 22%;
    }
}
```

The margin left of 22% results from a default label width of 20% and an additional margin-right of 2% for the label. The css class `.ui-my-addition-element-info` is not a default jquerymobile class but I tried to match the naming scheme as close as possible.

Comment: This looks fragile (in case the theme contains different than `22%` and `450px` rules). Isn't there a JQM standard way of marking text up to be aligned with form elements?

Comment: I would have suggested to write a less or sass template but there is no css framework included in jquery mobile. But since I keep my modifications inside an additional file and themes are not frequently changed I would say this is a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want to achieve http://jsfiddle.net/z8w6r/13/ ?

Comment: or this: http://jsfiddle.net/LU7PT/ +1 to you I won't put any answer as you got it what I wanna say anyways +1 `:)`

Comment: That nails it! But I was wondering whether that is possible using jquerymobile markup rather than creating custom javascript code that is more or less clutter to my codebase and also very specific at this point.

Comment: sorry, I'm not familiar with jquerymobile.